# Restify/Node.js - POST parameters not being read from time to time

Tags: node.js, rest, restify

We have implemented a REST API using Restify and Node.js. There is a current issue where we have a certain set of parameters and when tested in `environment1` it works properly. However, when the same set of parameters are used and tested in `environment2`, the API returns an error that there are missing parameters. After restarting the API, it starts working again. Nothing appears in the logs though.

Sample body parameters:

```
{
   "records" : [
      {"param1" : "param1val", "param2" : "param2val"},
      {"param2" : "param2val", "param2" : "param2val"}
   ]
}
```

This is how the values are being accessed.

```
let data = req.body
let records = data.records

if (records == undefined) {
   res.send(...)
   return
}

else {
   // use the values of records
}
```

So what happens is sometimes, the code for returning an error message that there are no parameters are triggered (although in reality the parameters are complete) from time to time. But after a while, using the same set of parameters, it proceeds successfully.

Restify version is 7.7.0. Node.js version is 10.15.3.

Has anyone encountered this before? What needs to be done to resolve this?

Comment: That's a little too vague. Do you have any code examples? Where are these parameters located? What errors are you getting? How are the parameters being initiated? How are they being accessed?

Comment: Ignore the question about where the parameters are located and being initiated. I wasn't thinking about POST parameters. The other three questions still stand.

Comment: +HeadCode, I updated the post. Thanks!